# How to improve the Docker image build time when CI tool used is GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, github-actions

We have a java application which uses maven, docker and Github actions.

The below snippet is from our Dockerfile.

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-openj9 AS builder
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
RUN mvn clean install
```

And then we have a deploy.yml for GitHub actions. The issue is that on GitHub actions, maven always downloads the dependencies and then creates a jar and finally a docker image is created.

Using below tutorial, I have tried to implement caching in GitHub actions.
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/build-images-on-github-actions-with-docker-layer-caching

The key for the cache in my case is calculated as below:
key: ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ hashFiles('pom.xml') }}

Also made the following changes in the Dockerfile.

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-openj9 AS builder
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
RUN mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies
ADD . .
RUN mvn install
```

Still I do not see any significant changes in the reduction in build time.
What I am trying to do is that I want the maven dependencies download as a separate layer in docker image, and caching this docker layer which can be later re-used in the final docker image build.

If anyone can shade a light on this issue.

Comment: I don't know you should somehow check your image,may be with docker history.

Comment: I have same problem, "npm ci" keeps to reinstalling dependencies in action. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use Buildkit([buildkit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit)),now it is already part of every Docker Engine(19 and latest versions for sure).
Very nice Medium post
[Introducing buildkit](https://blog.mobyproject.org/introducing-buildkit-17e056cc5317)

This is nice example which you can use

[docker cache ci](https://testdriven.io/blog/faster-ci-builds-with-docker-cache/)

although with Python.

Reagarding the CI environment,Github Actions has fantastic [build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/)

Example

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "master"

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      # Check out code
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # This is the a separate action that sets up buildx runner
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      # So now you can use Actions' own caching!
      - name: Cache Docker layers
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: /tmp/.buildx-cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ github.sha }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      # And make it available for the builds
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: false
          tags: user/app:latest
          cache-from: type=local,src=/tmp/.buildx-cache
          cache-to: type=local,dest=/tmp/.buildx-cache-new
      - name: Move cache
        run: |
          rm -rf /tmp/.buildx-cache
          mv /tmp/.buildx-cache-new /tmp/.buildx-cache
```

Comment: yes I am using the same, but this is not working as mentioned in the question. I have provided the link for buildkit tutorial as well.